# Checking a variable in js that is directly in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have one file, that is **external** from my index.html page, named *code.js* with this code on it:

```
function parse() {
    if (a === 1) 
        alert("a equals 1");
}

(function() {
    parse();
})();
```

As I said, that file is called *code.js*.
Now, I have an index.html file that is in the same folder/directory as the code.js file. Now, this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="code.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = 1;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Javascript</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I want to be able for the code.js file to use the variable from my javascript that is in the index.html file. I am doing this because I am going to make my own javascript library, but I need to do learn this first. Any solutions?

Comment: So what error or unexpected behavior are you experiencing?  What have you tried to troubleshoot or solve the issue on your own?

Comment: replace the order of the script tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of your `script` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 1;
</script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

This way, the global variable `a` will be initialized before the `parse` method in `code.js` is called.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Robby said, browsers load a page in order from top to bottom, left to right, because that is how they are written ([sort of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)). This means in your supplied code, `code.js` is loaded and run before you set `a=1`. As Robby mentioned, you can easily switch the order of your `<script>` tags and be fine.

This applies to other elements as well, so any *other* elements will not be accessible before their place in the HTML document. For example, a `<div>` in the body cannot be referenced by code run in the head, because the body has not been loaded yet. You can circumvent this by adding a `<script>` tag at the end of your HTML document, to be run after the main document has been loaded, but not necessarily all other external data like images (external scripts should be fine, however). The snippet below is what I have found works best:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <!-- Any script here could be anywhere (embedded/external) and in any order -->
        <script>
          function ready() {
            document.getElementById('a').textContent = 'a = ' + a;
          }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = 1;
        </script>
        <!-- <script src="code.js"></script> - load external code here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Javascript</h1>
        <div id="a">a = ?</div>
        <script>ready(); // Runs code after document is initialized</script>
    </body>
</html>
```